# How to run the website when the configs are encrypted?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a website built using C# and ASP.NET whose configuration has been encrypted. I have found method encrypt and decrypt in dll file.
Is there any method that can run the website normally?

Here is the dll code

```
...

        // Token: 0x0600001A RID: 26 RVA: 0x00002610 File Offset: 0x00000810
        public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt)
        {
            byte[] toEncryptArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
            string key = BM_Define.keyEncode;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            tdes.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }

        // Token: 0x0600001B RID: 27 RVA: 0x000026A4 File Offset: 0x000008A4
        public static string Decrypt(string cipherString)
        {
            byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);
            string key = BM_Define.keyEncode;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            hashmd5.Clear();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tdes.Key = keyArray;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            tdes.Clear();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
        }
```

here is web.config

```xml
...
    <!--Mssql-->
    <add key="CMSMsSqlIP" value="8i/bBREVoBbR4yKnAMrseQ==" />
    <add key="CMSMsSqlUser" value="c4DjF4M1yRA=" />
    <add key="CMSMsSqlPass" value="TNP6j8p798PvKBW1I+WoPw==" />
    <add key="CMSMsSqlDB" value="dusp+2wfjsA=" />
    <!--ws-->
    <add key="UWS" value="4ttxV+IwwcI=" />
    <add key="PWS" value="UXLBnxu62dQ=" />
    <!--Email-->
    <!--define User-->
    <add key="CountUser" value="1" />
    <add key="CPUser1" value="4ttxV+IwwcI=" />
    <add key="CPPass1" value="UXLBnxu62dQ=" />
    <add key="CPIP1" value="8i/bBREVoBbR4yKnAMrseQ==" />
...
```

Is there any method that can run the website normally?

Comment: What do you mean by *running the website normally?* What problems are you encountering?

Comment: I can't run the website because its values are being encrypted, can you help me?

Comment: Encryption and Decryption typically involves the use of a KEY.  Do you have the KEY that was used to encrypt these settings values?  You will need that KEY to successfully decrypt the encrypted values.